# How to smooth scroll on click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I want to be able to smooth scroll to a specific div using its id but my current script isn't correct. Can anyone see where my error is?

Here is my fiddle for reference [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wn6rv94t/2/).

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 5000);
    return false;
        });
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to add script tag in jsfiddle. Try with this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/wn6rv94t/1/
Removed`<script></script>`

Comment: thanks, any idea why it wouldn't work on my site that's set just like the fiddle?

Comment: press F12 check for browser console ....there must be error. just rectify it or tell me what's the error

Comment: only console feed back i get is about my font resources import type. the script is being ignored